# Workbox with angular

Tags: angular, workbox

I have installed the workbox-cli and excepted the default settings added a little script to the `package.json` file and called the command `workbox generate:sw` 
To produce the `sw.js` file I just run `npm run generate-sw` and this then gives me the `sw.js` fle with all the files and revisions. 
I have added the script to check and run the service worker in the index.html at the bottom

```
  <script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && 'PushManager' in window) {
  // console.log('Service Worker and Push is supported');

  navigator.serviceWorker.register('src/sw.js')
  .then(function(swReg) {
    console.log('Service Worker is registered', swReg);
    // swRegistration = swReg;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Service Worker Error', error);
  });
} else {
  console.warn('Push messaging is not supported');
  // pushButton.textContent = 'Push Not Supported';
}
```

When I run the angular app it builds all the files and always gives the error `Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script`
I have changes the `swDest` in the `workbox-cli-config` but cant get it to add the `sw.js` file. Am I missing something with what angular is doing?

I also have tried putting the script in the `main.ts` and trying to register there but still get the same error.

Workbox looks so easy!

Comment: Can you share your workbox-cli-config.js file also ?

Comment: I have changed the src config to the dist folder, this has made the difference but still having problems with the vendor.folder size issue

Answer (score 2):

I will share my working version with Angular 6 CLI.
This is my `workbox-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "dist/app",
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{txt,ico,html,js,css,jpg,png,gif,svg}"
  ],
  "swDest": "dist\\app\\sw.js",
  "swSrc": "sw-src.js",
  "maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes": 52428800
};
```

I'm registering service worker in my `main.ts`

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(() => registerServiceWorker())
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

function registerServiceWorker() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register('/sw.js')
      .then(reg => {
        console.log('[App] Successful service worker registration', reg);
        if (!navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
          console.log('controller is not ready. reloading');
          location.reload();
        }
      })
      .catch(err =>
        console.error('[App] Service worker registration failed', err)
      );
  } else {
    console.error('[App] Service Worker API is not supported in current browser');
  }
}
```

`sw-src.js` is in the root folder, same level as `workbox-config.js`:

```
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/3.5.0/workbox-sw.js");
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);
workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute('/index.html');
```

And this is how I run the app. Notice that I use http-server to serve it.

```
"start:sw": "ng build && workbox injectManifest && cd dist/app && http-server -c-1 -cors"
```